# How to deal with the original pointer after it is deleted and erased in the vector?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have below code. I think all of 3 elements in the vector can be deleted and erased correctly, but the original pointer t1, t2, t3 become dangling pointers, right ? It looks like a problem if they are used in somewhere else. How to deal with them ?

```
typedef struct test
{
    test(int i, int j): a(i), b(j){}
    int a;
    int b;
}Test;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test* t1 = new test(1, 2);
    test* t2 = new test(1, 4);
    test* t3 = new test(1, 8);

    vector<test*> testList;
    testList.push_back(t1);
    testList.push_back(t2);
    testList.push_back(t3);

    for(auto it = testList.begin(); it!=testList.end();)
    {
        delete (*it);
        *it = nullptr;
        it = testList.erase(it);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing you can do about that. It's no different from any other situation where you delete what a pointer points to, you have to make sure you don't use any other variables that hold the same pointger.

Comment: Consider ways to avoid expressing ownership via raw pointers. First of all, can you use containers directly instead of `new`-ing? If so, do so. But if  you must `new`, then immediately put the raw pointer in a smart pointer (to manage it), such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. Raw pointers have their uses, e.g. to just refer to objects. But those uses do not include expressing ownership. Voting to close as **too broad**.

Comment: The solution is to use better abstractions and mechanisms. A naive solution would be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test>>`. A better solution would be `std::vector<test>`.

Comment: You can use [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: You fix it by making sure there are no pointers to dangle. There are at least 3 good ways to do that. Encapsulation, smart pointers, no pointers.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think in my project the best solution is to use smart pointer. Thanks for your help.